# postData not working in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, html, json, django, jqgrid

I am trying to add a new row to the JqGrid Table, the json sent in the request is received by the server. Now I am trying to add new parameter to the json using the

```
postData : {my_parameter: "my_id"}
```

but still `my_parameter` is not sent.

I have also tried keeping the `mtype : "GET"` , still its not sending my custom parameter in the json.
Please could you help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
   jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
    data: griddata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: "auto",
    colNames:[' ', 'ID','Activity Name', 'Phase'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'myac',index:'', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false,
            formatter:'actions',
            formatoptions:{
                keys:true,
                //delbutton: false,//disable delete button

                delOptions:{recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm:beforeDeleteCallback},
                //editformbutton:true, editOptions:{recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm:beforeEditCallback}
            }
        },
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:activity_val}},
        {name:'phase',index:'phase', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Phase1:Phase I;Phase2:Phase II;Other:Other"}},
    ],

    viewrecords : true,
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager : pager_selector,
    altRows: true,
    gridview: true,
    //toppager: true,

    multiselect: false,
    //multikey: "ctrlKey",
    multiboxonly: true,

    loadComplete : function() {
        var table = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            styleCheckbox(table);

            updateActionIcons(table);
            updatePagerIcons(table);
            enableTooltips(table);
        }, 0);
    },
    editurl: '/del_row/',//nothing is saved
    cellEdit: true,
    postData: {MyId :function() { return $('#MyId').val();}},
    caption: "Activty Phase Mapping"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`postData` will be used **only during filling the grid if you use non local data** (`url` is defined and you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "json"`).

If you need to post additional parameters **during editing** of the grid you should use options or callbacks which corresponds the editing mode which you use. The code which you posted uses cell editing (`cellEdit: true`). So you need to specify URL to which the data will be posted using `cellurl` parameter. You can use for example `beforeSubmitCell` callback to extend the data which will be sent to the URL:

```
cellEdit: true,
cellurl: '/someUrl',
beforeSubmitCell: function () {
    return { MyId: return $('#MyId').val() };
}
```

In the above code I replaced additionally `cellurl`